# sha512-crypt mysql and dovecot

Tags: mysql, sha512, dovecot, sha2

I have a question about understanding sha512-crypt hashing. I found this [tutorial](https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix2.9.6-dovecot2.0.19-mysql) to set up dovecot and postfix with mysql. I followed the tutorial (with slight modifications) and everything works fine. But there is one thing, that I do not understand:

To add a user, I should use:

```
INSERT INTO `mailserver`.`virtual_users`
  (`id`, `domain_id`, `password` , `email`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', ENCRYPT('firstpassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))),    'email1@example.com'),
  ('2', '1', ENCRYPT('secondpassword', CONCAT('$6$', SUBSTRING(SHA(RAND()), -16))), 'email2@example.com');
```

and again, this works perfectly fine, i.e. I can log in with my password (and only my password) to dovecot. But why? If I see it right, it encrypts the password with a random salt, but it doesn't save it anywhere. So hashing the same password twice gives me 2 different hashes (I tried it). So my question boils down to:
Could I get a brief explanation of sha-512 (which I couldn't find online) and and explanation as to why these lines work?

Thanks already

Comment: Have you found the query that matches the password / user against the database by any chance?

Comment: yes, it's: `password_query = SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = '%u'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The salt is saved as part of the password. For example calling:

```
ENCRYPT('firstpassword', CONCAT('$6$', 'FooBarBaz'))
```

Gives

> $6$FooBarBaz$.T.G.7FRJqZ6N2FF7b3BEkr5j37CWhwgvPOOoccrr0bvkBbNMmLCxzqQqKJbNhnhC.583dTBLEuZcDuQe7NEe.

This stores both the algorithm used (6 being SHA512) and the salt ('FooBarBaz') both delinated by `$`.

Edit: To check a password you can use:

```
password = ENCRYPT('user_input', `password`)
```

`ENCRYPT` will grab the salt from the stored password and use this when checking `user_input`.

Full credit to hek2mgl for the password check he detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16485963/505722).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it. Does mysql have an easy way to match a password against a string that's saved like that in the database? I.e. a function which I can give `$6$FooBarBaz$.T.G.7FRJqZ6N2FF7b3BEkr5j37CWhwgvPOOoccrr0bvkBbNMmLCxzqQqKJbNhnhC.583dTBLEuZcDuQe7NEe` and a password to match it against as arguments returning a true or false somehow?

Comment: @ciem ENCRYPT can be used for that to. I'll edit in an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dovecot directly to generate the hash.

Use:

```
sudo doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT
```

This will ask you for a password for the user you are trying to make and return to you a string that you can copy and paste into your MYSQL database.

```sql
INSERT INTO `mailserver`.`virtual_users`
  (`id`, `domain_id`, `password` , `email`)
VALUES
  (1, 1, '{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$5kJy...', 'email1@example.com'),
  (...)
  ;
```