# how to SHA512-CRYPT for Dovecot in JAVA?

Tags: java, sha512, dovecot

I have a Dovecot server with MySQL database for storing usernames and passwords. The passwords in the database are in SHA512-CRYPT scheme.

I am inserting the hashed passwords in the database using a script.

```
doveadm pw -s SHA512-CRYPT -p password -r 500000
```

I want to hash the passwords using a JAVA application. I found [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186158/sha512-crypt-mysql-and-dovecot) and I tried to create the same resulting hash using same password `firstpassword` and salt `FooBarBaz`. For some reason the resulting hash I get is different, although I am using the same hashing algorithm, salt and password.

Here is my Java code:

```
byte[] password = "firstpassword".getBytes();
byte[] salt = "FooBarBaz".getBytes();

MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
digest.reset();
digest.update(salt);
byte[] hashed = digest.digest(password);

String encodedHash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashed);

System.out.printf("{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$%s$%s", "FooBarBaz",encodedHash);
```

This outputs the hash:

```
{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$FooBarBaz$5WPtOnXVI/a6f003WByGKIcsfa6x0ansxiyE8uEfJ0TE5pI+Rv9kcMLgdZboKg7ZSWQgWFg+pIqruvdg6aiP/g==
```

I also tried swapping the order of salt + password to make it:

```
digest.update(password);
byte[] hashed = digest.digest(salt);
```

this gives me:

```
{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$FooBarBaz$QWS8+W5EWhModF+uO2tcsd55tDxzdzGJ5FurIbEgwVCwKfT5UqwIvBNG1Oyws8bZEFdeGgyD0u6zS1KArvGf9Q==
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I accomplish the same hash results in Java if I use the same password and salt?

The hash I am looking for is:

```
{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$FooBarBaz$.T.G.7FRJqZ6N2FF7b3BEkr5j37CWhwgvPOOoccrr0bvkBbNMmLCxzqQqKJbNhnhC.583dTBLEuZcDuQe7NEe.
```

Comment: I guess, sha will generate random hashes for same strings and salts. You just have to check them using builtin check functions

Comment: @waplet that's not true. Same input = same hash, that's one basic requirement of every hashing algorithm. Furthermore, the op asks explicitly how to create those hashes, not to check them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`doveadm` uses the Unix [crypt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) family of functions to generate the hash and outputs the hash as a Base64 encoded string.  The alphabet used for the encoding (by `crypt`) is `[a-zA-Z0-9./]` (as mentioned on the man page for the functions).  However, the alphabet used by the `java.util.Base64` class is `[A-Za-z0-9+/]` (compliant with `RFC 4648`, as mentioned on the [JavaDoc page for the Base64 class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)).  Therefore, even if the hashed values are the same, they will get encoded differently.

A reliable option is to use the `Crypt` class from [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) as `Crypt.crypt("firstpassword", "$6$FooBarBaz")` (The prefix `$6$` is mandatory to instruct `Crypt` that the `SHA512-CRYPT` algorithm needs to be used).  This will generate your expected hash value.

Comment: Thank you manish.. could you also add in your answer that it's possible to to specify the number of iterations "rounds".. with `Crypt.crypt("firstpassword", "$6$rounds=123123$FooBarBaz")` I already tried it and it works perfectly

Comment: It's not only the different alphabet, the crypt() function uses an algorithm that is based on the SHA-512 digest but also takes a salt value into account and then does several thousand rounds of SHA-512 just to make it slower and thus brute-forcing less likely.
Using Apache Commons Codec Crypt.crypt() is the correct solution nevertheles!

Comment: You sir are a life-safer! A single upvote is not enough to show my gratitude. So expect more than that ;-)

Comment: I created a simple webservice based on your answer to generate Dovecot hashes: https://passwordhasher.projecttac.com/